# Behaviour of deparse and substitute when using write_csv

Tags: r, csv, tidyverse

Had created a function that would do a bit of filtering for me, and replace anything that was not one of the primary categories with "other" that I then wanted to quickly save as an individual CSV to use in generating a presentation. I was passing into the function the object reference `col` so the working function looks like this.

```
separate_values <- function(df, col) {

  ...

  file_name <- paste0("data/other_",
                      deparse(substitute(col)),
                      ".csv")
  other_df %>%
    as.data.frame %>% 
    write_csv(file_name)

  ...

}
```

In the situation where `col = support` this produces the file "other_support.csv". However when the code is instead as follows...

```
separate_values <- function(df, col) {

  ...

  other_df %>%
    as.data.frame %>% 
    write_csv(paste0("data/other_",
                      deparse(substitute(col)),
                      ".csv"))

  ...

}
```

...this consistently produces the file "other_col.csv". I am asking here about this because clearly I have found a solution to my issue, but I want to know **WHY** this is happening?

Also maybe there is a better way to go about this?